# If I declare a char array do I have to count the null character too?

Tags: c

For example:

```
char array[][5] = {"game", "house"};
```

Is `house` suitable for the array or do I have to add the null character so I have to declare like this:

`char array[][6] = {"game", "house"};`

Comment: @xing but if I compile it and print it, it works with 5 columns.

Comment: @xing it prints "housegame game"

Comment: @xing why does it print "housegame game"?

Comment: If you want to store an N-character *string* in an array, then the array needs to be at least N+1 elements wide to account for the 0 terminator.  Yes, you can fit `{‘h’, ‘o’, ‘u’, ‘s’, ‘e’}` into a 5-element array, but that’s not a *string*, and if you pass that array as an argument to something that expects a string, you’ll probably get unexpected results.

Comment: @xing: Generally, compilers should not warn on `char array[][5] = {"game", "house"};`. It is strictly conforming C to initialize an array that just fits the explicit characters and does not have room for the terminating null character.

Comment: user11006304, "it prints "housegame game" --> Post the code that is doing that to add clarity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you will use the array as a *string*, it must include the terminating null character. The terminating null character is part of the array and must be included in its size.

Many of the standard C library routines take arguments that are *strings*, which are arrays of characters terminated by a null character.

It is also possible to use an array of characters for your own purposes, without passing it to a standard library function that requires a string. If this is how you will use the array, it does not need to include a terminating null character.

When you are initializing such an array with string literals, you do not need to include space for the terminating null character in the size of the array. The terminating null character in the string literal will be used to initialize an array element only if there is room for it.

Comment: Detail: "library routines take arguments that are _pointers to_ strings"

Comment: @chux: Per 7.1.1 1, a *string* is “a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first character.” That describes an array (per 6.2.5 20, an *array type* describes a “contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects with a particular member object type”). So, to pass a string is to pass an array, which is converted to a pointer to its first character. Passing a pointer to a string would be passing `char (*)[]`, which is wrong. Clause 7 does use “pointer to string” as you would, but it is nonetheless inconsistent. We could say “pointer to the first character of a string.”

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you intend to do with the strings.

The definition

```
char array[][5] = {"game", "house"};
```

will initialise `array` with dimension `2` and `5`.    `array[0]` will be initialised with the elements `'g', 'a', 'm', 'e', '\0'`   and `array[1]` as `'h', 'o', 'u', 's', 'e'`.    Note the absence of the terminating `'\0'` on `array[1]`.

What happens then depends on what your code subsequently does with the array.   For example;

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
   for (j = 0; j < 5, ++j)
   {
       if (array[i][j] != '\0')
           printf("%c", array[i][j]);
       else
           j = 5;    /*   terminate the inner loop */
   }       
   printf("\n");
}
```

will happily print two lines with `game` and `house` to the `stdout`, since the loops specifically limit themselves to not accessing an array element out of bounds.

However,

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
   printf("%s\n", array[i]);
}
```

will have undefined behaviour, since the `%s` format will print every character of `array[i]` until a terminating `'\0'` is found.   Since `array[1]` is initialised with no terminating `'\0'`,  `printf()` will typically run past the end of the array  i.e. loop through whatever memory happens to be located immediately past the end of `array`, and print whatever garbage it finds until it happens to find a character with value `'\0'`.  If there is no such character within memory available to the program, then the program may simply keep printing garbage characters and then crash (e.g. if the host operating system detects the program accessing memory it shouldn't and then forceably terminates the program).

The general rule is:  if you are using any functions which ASSUME the presence of a terminating `'\0'`  (`printf()` with the `%s` format, `strcat()`, `strcmp()`, etc etc)  then it is necessary to ensure that terminator is present.   This means ensuring the array has enough elements AND initialising one of those elements to `'\0'`.

If you instead initialise `array` as

```
char array[][6] = {"game", "house"};
```

then both `array[0]` and `array[1]` have the required terminator.

Answer (score 3):

```
char array[][5] = {"game", "house"};
```

> Is `house` suitable for the array

Yes. "house" is suitable to initialize  the *array* `array[1]`.  `array[1]`, though, is not a *string* as it lacks a *null character*.  `array[0]` is a *string*.  Both `array[1]` and `array[0]` are arrays of `char`.

---

> try `char array[][5] = { "house", "game"}`
>   it prints "housegame game"

That problem is with `print("%s", array[0]);`.  `"%s"` expects a matching pointer to a *string*.  Here, `array[0]` is not a *string*.

To print a character array that that may/may not be a *string*, use a *precision*.  Printing will stop when the *precision* is met or when encountering a *null character*.

```
char array[][5] = { "house", "game"};
print("<%.*s>\n", 5, array[0]);
print("<%.*s>\n", 5, array[1]);
```

Output

```
<house>
<game>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a remark: That silently eating the terminal NULL character of string literals is a feature of C only. In C++ it is forbidden to provide initialization strings that are bigger than the array to be initialized.

Comment: While this remark is true,  it is superfluous since the question is tagged as C and not as C++.